# Long menu item in Java AWT application not visible

Tags: java, awt, xserver

When I start Java application with AWT GUI on remote server that uses my local X-server (Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity), menu items with long names are not visible. It is very interesting that I can see this behavior only on one specific server whilst it works on others.

Demonstration code is:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Menu;
import java.awt.MenuBar;
import java.awt.MenuItem;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class Main extends Frame {

    public Main() {
            this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
            });
        Menu mn = new Menu("File");
        MenuItem mi = new MenuItem("It is very very long text");
        mn.add(mi);
        mi = new MenuItem("long");
        mn.add(mi);
        MenuBar mb = new MenuBar();
        mb.add(mn);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setMenuBar(mb);
        this.setSize(200,200);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it behave differently if you change the body of your `main` method to `EventQueue.invokeLater(Main::new);`?

Comment: No, it behaves same.